# emacs python indentation for single line if else

Tags: python, emacs, syntax

When I have a brief if-else statement where each action is a single line, I like to use the format:

```
    if( cond ): print "True"
    else:       print "False"
```

I personally find this to be the most, elegant, concise and readable.  Emacs, however, does not agree.  It wants to indent it as:

```
    if( cond ): print "True"
else:       print "False"
```

Is there any way to change this behavior?  I'm using emacs 24.3.1, and the python.el major-mode.

Comment: My Emacs configuration for Python 3.3 handles it correctly (then again, Emacs 24.2.1).

Comment: Might there be another problem in the code before? It would then often result in this kind of behavior.

Comment: check what `M-x indent-region` does when you just select the two lines.

Comment: @Dualinity no, this is very consistent recurring behavior

Comment: @Dualinity indent-region has the same effect

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me then. You could always try to see if there is something that raises suspicion in `M-x customize-group RET python`; I do not see anything there though for my version.

Comment: I see the same behavior as OP in emacs 24.3.1

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs-24.3, every time I hit TAB on the `else' line, it switchwes between the two indentations (the correct one and the incorrect one).  So there's indeed a bug in that the incorrect indentation should not be suggested, but at least the correct indentation is among the choices offered.

Maybe it's related to http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15163.

Comment: Interesting; I'm not even getting the correct indentation as an option.  I did submit a bug report, but I don't think it has been posted yet.